# Возможна ли веб-разработка на котлине?

Tags: веб-программирование, kotlin

Очень нравится этот язык своим синтаксисом, но он же в основном на андроид ориентирован насколько я понимаю. Возможно ли его как-то приспособить для сервера? Spring/Play... или что-то еще. И насколько это уже распространено (веб на котлине)?

P.S. Я в курсе что он в жс компилироваться может, но я в основном бэкэндщик и мне интересен он именно со стороны серверной разработки.

Comment: Ну, JS можно запускать на NodeJS, и вот вам сервер.

Comment: @D-side Да ну, бред какой-то... А как подключить библиотеки ноды к котлину? Это же жс библиотеки. Стремно звучит как-то.

Comment: Я к тому, что теоретически это реально. Библиотеки на JS в таких языках обычно подключаются посредством экстернов (определений в типах без реализации) или непроверяемыми блоками кода (untyped в haxe, например). Но это извращения, конечно. Вебсерверы на JVM нередки.

Comment: @D-side так я и не имею ничего против JVM. Я про нее и говорил. Хз че вы на жс перевели разговор.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kotlin не ориентирован в основном на Android, тут вы глубоко заблуждаетесь.
Android просто оказался благоприятной нишей, в которой разработчики заждались чего-то нового, сидя на Java 6.

Есть официальная страница на сайте Kotlin-a о web-девелопменте:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/server-overview.html

На конференции, что была недавно в Сан Франциско, ребята из JetBrains очень активно продвигали свой собственный фреймворк Ktor, с него и советую начать.
https://github.com/ktorio/ktor

Kotlin язык широкого применения, и областей его применения будет все больше и больше, над этим сейчас в JetBrains активно работают.

Все видео с KotlinConf 2017
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spFtUgL32yA&list=PLQ176FUIyIUY6UK1cgVsbdPYA3X5WLam5

Comment: Посмотрю. В России как-то про это вообще не слышно. Даже на хабре не пишут. Поэтому и складывается впечатление что котлин только для ведра.